# Как получить полное имя файла в одну команду?

Tags: linux, файлы, shell

Как получить полное (с путём относительно `/`) имя файла в одну команду?

Бывает, работаешь в консоли, и нужно скопировать `/полный/путь/к/файлу`, например, чтобы в соседней консоли использовать его как аргумент для `scp`. Приходится вызывать `pwd`, чтобы скопировать путь к текущей папке, и `ls`, чтобы скопировать имя файла. Можно ли это сделать в одну команду?

Comment: Например, `find 'pwd'/имя_файла` (кавычки вокруг `pwd` - обратные). Или ещё куча вариантов, например, с `readlink`, как указано в ответе ниже. Количество команд и/или аргументов при этом не имеет вообще никакого значения, ибо есть алиасы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`readlink -f` покажет `/полный/путь/к/файлу.ext`, дополнительно "раскрыв" все символические ссылки и заменив их на "канонические" пути. Пример показателен:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/bar.ext
$ ln -s foo/bar.ext baz.ext
$ readlink -f foo/bar.ext 
/tmp/foo/bar.ext
$ readlink -f baz.ext 
/tmp/foo/bar.ext
```

Здесь `/tmp/baz.ext` является симлинком на `/tmp/foo/bar.ext`.

Предложенное решение работает в Linux и FreeBSD, но не работает в Mac OS - у них там [своя атмосфера](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1116890/1688077).

Answer (score 4):

Предложу вариант чуть понавороченней:

```
readlink -m файл | tr -d '\r\n' | xsel -b
```

То есть:

1. Читаем полный путь
2. Сразу же копируем его в буфер обмена, предварительно ...
3. ... вырезав конечные СR/LF (если не хотим, чтобы они добавлялись при вставке)

Answer (score 2):

Для файлов относительно текущего каталога

```
echo ~+/file
```

или с тем же результатом

```
echo $PWD/file
```

Answer (score 1):

можно, например, подставлять то, что содержится в переменной окружения `$PWD` (или в любой другой переменной окружения), даже без «команды», а всего лишь клавиатурным сочетанием. если, конечно, ваша оболочка использует [*gnu/readline*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) для редактирования командной строки.

---

например, такая команда привяжет к клавиатурному сочетанию <kbd>alt+o</kbd> подстановку значения переменной `$PWD` (и слэша в конце — для удобства) в текущую позицию курсора:

```
$ bind '"\eo": "$PWD/\e\C-e"'
```

здесь `\eo` — это и есть <kbd>alt+o</kbd> (а, например, `\C-o` — это <kbd>ctrl+o</kbd>).

чтобы данная привязка создавалась автоматически в каждой сессии оболочки, можно добавить приведённую команду, например, в стартовый скрипт используемой оболочки — `~/.${SHELL##*/}rc`.

а ещё лучше — добавить строку, которая в примере выше передавалась встроенной команде оболочки *bind*, прямо в файл `~/.inputrc` (конф. файл, используемый *gnu/readline*-ом):

```
"\eo": "$PWD/\e\C-e"
```

---

навеяно этим ответом: [Bash: call script with customized keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120926/4827341)